# Show the number of notifications in the page title

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notifications

I posted this suggestion earlier in [this question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1532/mostrar-n%C3%BAmero-de-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-na-barra-de-t%C3%ADtulo) at the Portuguese Stack Overflow Meta, and they suggested that I post it here.

---

Currently, the tab shows the number of new questions:

> [image: SO Tab]

Wouldn't be more useful to have the number of notifications instead?

In the Meta questions linked above, @Bacco suggested it would be a nice idea to have a mixed format:

> `(Questions|Notifications) Stack ...`

In this case, if there no new notifications or questions, it would be shown a `0`:

> `(0|2) Stack ...`
>   or
>   `(2|0) Stack ...`

---

Another alternative: let the user choose if he/she wants to see the number of questions or notifications.

What do you think, friends?

Comment: I rely on that number, and would find a second number showing notifications to be confusing. The new post number changes much more rapidly, the posts number changes far less often and is shown on all pages you visit anyway.

Comment: I think the number could be useful only on your user profile page, which you could then leave open for that purpose. Otherwise as @Martijn said, it's just too confusing to see two numbers